# Read specific columns of a delimited file in SAS

Tags: sas

This seems like it should be straightforward, but I can't find how to do this in the documentation. I want to read in a comma-delimited file, but it's very wide, and I just want to read a few columns.

I thought I could do this, but the `@` pointer seems to point to columns of the text rather than the column numbers defined by the delimiter:

```
data tmp;
 infile 'results.csv' delimiter=',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl=32767 firstobs=2;
 @1 id
 @5 name$
run;
```

In this example, I want to read just what is in the 1st and 5th columns based on the delimiter, but SAS is reading what is in position 1 and position 5 of text file. So if the first line of the input file starts like this

> 1234567, "x", "y", "asdf", "bubba", ... more variables ...

I want `id=1234567` and `name=bubba`, but I'm getting `name=567, "`.

I realize that I could read in every column and drop the ones I don't want, but there must be a better way.

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, @ does point to column of text not the delimited column.  The only method using standard input I've ever found was to read in blank, ie

```
input
id
blank $
blank $
blank $ 
name $
;
```

and then drop blank.

However, there is a better solution if you don't mind writing your input differently.

```
data tmp;
 infile datalines;
 input @;
 id = scan(_INFILE_,1,',');
 name = scan(_INFILE_,5,',');
 put _all_;
 datalines;
12345,x,y,z,Joe
12346,x,y,z,Bob
;;;;
run;
```

It makes formatting slightly messier, as you need put or input statements for each variable you do not want in base character format, but it might be easier depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip fields fairly efficiently if you know a bit of INPUT statement syntax, note the use of (3*dummy)(:$1.). Reading just one byte should also improve performance slightly.

```
data tmp;
   infile cards DSD firstobs=2;
   input id $ (3*dummy)(:$1.) name $;
   drop dummy;
   cards;
id,x,y,z,name
1234567, "x", "y", "asdf", "bubba", ... more variables 
1234567, "x", "y", "asdf", "bubba", ... more variables 
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Comment: could you explain `(3*dummy)(:$1.)`? I've never seen this before and I actually am using it now after finding this post. Great info.

Comment: @DukeLuke The first parenthesized list (3*dummy) is a variable list, 3 says how many. Expanded is (dummy dummy dummy) .  The second parenthesized list if the informat list for the variable list.  (:$1) .  The colon is a modifier specifying use "LIST INPUT" with informat and $1. is the informat.  The number of elements in the informat list is shorter than the variable list so the informat list repeated for each variable.

Comment: This seemed to work fine for a file I was trying, at least for the first variable I wanted to encounter and read, after that SAS didn't like it... i.e.
`input (3*dummy)(:$1.) acct_num $ (38*dummy)(:$1.) anothervar $ (4*dummy)(:$1.) anothervar $ ;`... Any thoughts on this, or have you tried to use it in this manner? I also tried using SCAN as was another recommendation below, but couldn't get it to process for my second variable either, only the first..

Comment: I guess I'm asking, should this work in the manner I listed, creating a bunch of dummies, read myvar, create more dummies, read my var, repeated until file no longer needs read..

Comment: I think you should start a new question.  Show your data and the program you used.  "SAS didn't like it" is not much to go on.

Answer (score 0):

One more option that I thought of when answering a related question from another user.

```
filename  tempfile temp;

data _null_;
  set sashelp.cars;
  file tempfile dlm=',' dsd lrecl=32767;
  put (Make--Wheelbase) ($);
run;


data mydata;
  infile tempfile dlm=',' dsd truncover lrecl=32767;
  length _tempvars1-_tempvars100 $32;
  array _tempvars[100] $;
  input (_tempvars[*]) ($);
  make=_tempvars[1];
  type=_tempvars[3];
  MSRP=input(_tempvars[6],dollar8.);
  keep make type msrp;
run;
```

Here we use an array of effectively temporary (can't actually BE temporary, unfortunately) variables, and then grab just what we want specifying the columns.  This is probably overkill for a small file - just read in all the variables and deal with it - but for 100 or 200 variables where you want just 15, 18, and 25, this might be easier, as long as you know which column you want exactly.  (I could see using this in dealing with census data, for example, if you have it in CSV form.  It's very common to just want a few columns most of which are way down 100 or 200 columns from the starting column.)

You have to take some care with your lengths for the temporary array (has to be as long as your longest column that you care about!), and you have to make sure not to mess up the columns since you won't get to know if you mess up unless it's obvious from the data.