# How to read only select columns in infile statement

Tags: sas

I have a csv file with 100 columns. How do I only read a select few columns?

```
data temp;
  infile "test.csv" delimiter=',' dsd firstobs=2;
  length date $10.; 
  input date $; /*only want to read 5 columns that I choose;*/
run;
```

Comment: If it's the first 5 columns you can do it, if not then you need to read all, but you can KEEP only the variables you want.

Comment: See possible duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513964/read-specific-columns-of-a-delimited-file-in-sas?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184526/how-to-create-a-truncated-permanent-database-from-a-larger-file-in-sas?lq=1

Comment: I'm going to close in favor of Itsy's question because it was better written, and because Rob (and perhaps others) picked that as well as the duplicate.  I would love to see more answers on that question, though, in the vein of the other question - if @DWal or SRSwift want to make a similar answer (utilizing a KEEP Statement, in particular) on that question it would be best I think.